# jquery ui draggable droppable dynamic problem

Tags: ajax, dynamic, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I would like to create a jquery draggable/droppable area. The drop areas will be created dynamically by pulling data from an ajax return from a mysql database. I am able to create the dynamic areas, but when dragging the 'product' over the drop area it does not work. I also have two hard coded areas and they work as expected.
This is the code:

```
/* jquery draggable/droppable */
$(function(){
$(".draggable").draggable({
  revert : function(event, ui){
    $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {top : 0,left : 0};
    return !event;
  },
  containment : "#img-id",
  cancel: false
});

$('.snap-item').droppable({
  tolerance: "fit",
  accept: ".draggable",
  activeClass: "highlight",
  drop: function(event, ui){
    if(!confirm("Are you sure?")){
      ui.draggable.css({top: 0,left: 0});
      ui.helper.css({"background-color": ""});
    }else{
      console.log('dragged ' + ui.draggable.data('dragitem') + ' onto ' +    $(this).data("myval")); // dragitem
  $(this).removeClass("highlight").addClass("green");
    }
  },
  out: function (event, ui) {
    ui.helper.css({"background-color": ""});
    $(this).removeClass("green");
  }
});
});

/* HTML code */
<div class="box">
      <div id="droppable">
        <div class="snap">
          <div id="dynamic"></div>
          <div class="snap-item ui-widget-header" data-myval="Meat1" style="top:20%; left:50%;"><div class="location">Meat 1</div></div>
          <div class="snap-item ui-widget-header" data-myval="Meat2" style="top:10%; left:30%;"><div class="location">Meat 2</div></div>
          <img id="img-id" class="img-fluid test">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

/* jquery ajax code to get data from database */
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "queries/getCategories.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      data:{store_id:storeid},
      success: function(data){
        $.each(data,function(i,j){
        $("#dynamic").append("<div class='snap-item ui-widget-header' data-myval='myval2' style='left:" + j.left_pos + "%; top:" + j.top_pos + "%'>Testarea " + j.category_id + "</div>");
        console.log("top " + j.top_pos);

      });
      }
    });
```

This is a screenshot of the result:
[image: live vies]

As you can see, I can drag the 'Pork' to 'Meat 1' or 'Meat 2' since they were hard coded. But I can't drag it to any of the others since they were dynamically created.

I have searched and tried many solutions, but none seem to work and the jquery ui documentation is very, very limited and poor.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to find an answer myself.

First split the draggable/droppable code like this:

```
/* jquery draggable/droppable */
$(function(){
$(".draggable").draggable({
revert : function(event, ui){
    $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {top : 0,left : 0};
    return !event;
  },
  containment : "#img-id",
  cancel: false
});
});

function makeDroppable(){
$('.snap-item').droppable({
  tolerance: "fit",
  accept: ".draggable",
  activeClass: "highlight",
  drop: function(event, ui){
    if(!confirm("Are you sure?")){
      ui.draggable.css({top: 0,left: 0});
      ui.helper.css({"background-color": ""});
    }else{
      console.log('dragged ' + ui.draggable.data('dragitem') + ' onto ' +    $(this).data("myval")); // dragitem
  $(this).removeClass("highlight").addClass("green");
    }
  },
  out: function (event, ui) {
    ui.helper.css({"background-color": ""});
    $(this).removeClass("green");
  }
});
});
}
```

And then, it's a simple matter of adding the makeDroppable() at the end of the ajax call, like so:

```
/* jquery ajax code to get data from database */
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "queries/getCategories.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      data:{store_id:storeid},
      success: function(data){
        $.each(data,function(i,j){
        $("#dynamic").append("<div class='snap-item ui-widget-header' data-myval='myval2' style='left:" + j.left_pos + "%; top:" + j.top_pos + "%'>Testarea " + j.category_id + "</div>");
        console.log("top " + j.top_pos);
        makeDroppable(); // ADDED THIS !!
      });
      }
    });
```

That way, you don't initialise the drop action until the div's have all been added to the DOM.

Hope this helps someone!